# CSS and HTML error with positioning

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, overflow

So here is my code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  views WHERE viewer_ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'")      or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$serverViewsBeforeAdd = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM views WHERE     server_id='".$_GET['s']."'"));

if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
$commentform = "<form action='scripts/addcomment.php?s=".$_GET['s']."' method='POST'><textarea name='comment' style='max-width:98%;min-width:98%;min- height:40px;max-height:40px;' placeholder='Leave a Comment'></textarea><br /><input      type='submit' value='Post' style='float:right;margin-right:2%;'></form>";    
}else{
$commentform = "";  
}

if(empty($_SESSION['voted_'.$_GET['s']])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO views VALUES('','".$_GET['s']."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".time()."')");
$_SESSION['voted_'.$_GET['s']] = 1;
$serverViews = $serverViewsBeforeAdd + 1;
}else{
$serverViews = $serverViewsBeforeAdd;
}
?>

<style>
#serverTitle {
font-family: corbel;
font-size: 28px;
color: #767676;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
#viewServerRight {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
width:73%;
padding-left:1%;
border-left:solid 1px #666666;
}
#viewServerLeft {
width:25%;
position:relative;
}
#serverActions {
float:right;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:5px;
}
#serverStatsTitle {
font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
color: #CFA900;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
#serverStatsAwnser {
font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #6A6A6A;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
</style>
<?php
$s = $_GET['s'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id='".$s."'") or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows !== 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    if($row['server_owner'] == @$_SESSION['username']){
            $serverActionsEdit = "<a href='?p=editserver&s=".$row['id']."' class='button'>Edit</a>";
        }
    if(!empty($row['server_website'])){
            $serverActionsWebsite = "<a href='http://www.".$row['server_website']."' class='button' target='_blank'>Visit Website</a>";
        }
        $serverActionsVote = "<a href='scripts/vote.php?&s=".$row['id']."' class='button'>Vote</a>";
    $serverActionsVoteEmbed = "<a href='?p=voteembed&s=".$row['id']."' class='button'>Vote Embed Code</a>";

    @$serverActions = $serverActionsEdit." ".$serverActionsWebsite." ".$serverActionsVote." ".$serverActionsVoteEmbed;

    echo "<div id='viewServerLeft' align='center'>
    <span id='serverStatsTitle'>Votes</span>
    <br />
    <span id='serverStatsAwnser'>".$row['server_votes']."</span>
    <hr /><span id='serverStatsTitle'>Views</span>
    <br />
    <span id='serverStatsAwnser'>".$serverViews."</span></div>
    <div id='viewServerRight'><span id='serverTitle'>".$row['server_name']."</span><div id='serverActions'>".$serverActions."</div><hr /><br />".$row['server_description']."<br /><hr /><br /><h2>Comments</h2>".$commentform."</div>";
    echo "<title>".$row['server_name']." - ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."</title>";
}
}else{
echo "<h2><span style='color:red;'>ERROR 404</span>: Server with ID of ".$s." not found!</h2>";
echo "<title>404: Server Not Found!</title>";
}
?>
```

So what i want it to look like is that the "viewServerRight dont is on top of the #wrapper that have the following styles:

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:90%;
margin-top:160px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
-ms-border-radius:10px;
/*  padding:10px;  */
-ms-box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-o-box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[Link to page](http://topserverlist.tk/?p=view&s=1)

The way it is now #viewServerRight is on top of #wrapper and it dont make it bigger when it overflows like i want to, But #viewServerLeft makes the #wrapper overflow, So what appears to be the problem?

Short explaination: I want the #wrapper's height to be bigger when there is more content in #viewServerRight

Comment: Prepare a minimalistic example (e.g. jsfiddle) or at least attach a screenshot. Otherwise it's tough to help.

Comment: I added a link to the page since i dont have enough rep to add an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the viewServerRight's position is absolute it won't affect the height of wrapper. Now you have two options:

- change the position of viewServerRight to relative or static
- use Javascript or jquery. Get the outer height of viewServerRight and
  set the minimum height of wrapper accordingly.

EDIT:

Yes you're right, the first one will not work. Your whole approach requires you to set the position of the viewServerRight div to absolute, and if you remove the absolute positioning it will mess it up. Tell you what, remove any positioning from the left and right divs, set their float to left, and add two empty divs before and after the left and right divs. These two empty divs should have this css attributes:

```
clear: both;
```

I hope I was clear enough. Good luck :)

Comment: The lavascript one worked fine, But the other one didnt.

Thanks for the help :)